# How can I add a function based on the version of perl?

Tags: perl, versioning

I'm sorry if this had been asked, but I found it hard to search for.

I use Perl 5.12 locally but some of our machines use Perl 5.8.8 and they won't be updated for the time being.

For auditing I use 'say' on platform 5.12.

I've written a simple function to implement say on 5.8.8 but I don't want to use it on 5.12.

Is there a way to only use my say function on the older version of Perl and use the 'builtin' version of say on 5.12?

Comment: A solution specific to this problem is [`Perl6::Say`](http://p3rl-org/Perl6::Say).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `$^V` [special variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) to determine the version of the Perl interpreter:

```
BEGIN {
    if ($^V ge v5.10.1) {  # "say" first appeared in 5.10
        require feature;
        feature->import('say');
    }
    else {
        *say = sub { print @_, "\n" }
    }    
}
```

Comment: When I try to run this script, I get the following error: `"Name "main::say" used only once: possible typo at C:\src\map.pl line 14."`

Comment: @chollida It's a warning, not an error. Try `no warnings 'once';`

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
BEGIN{
  no warnings 'once';
  unless( eval{
    require feature;
    feature->import('say');
    1
  } ){
    *say = sub{
       print @_, "\n";
     }
  }
}
```